# How do I insert more than one record at a time using Mongomapper?

Tags: ruby, mongodb, mongomapper

Mongmapper lets me easily create a new record as such

```
Track.create!({:name => "Obla di"})
```

Though I can't figure out how to insert more than one at a time as such

```
tracks = [{:name => "Obla di"}, {:name => "She Sang di"}]
Track.create!(tracks)
```

I know that I could just loop over the array and insert them one at a time but I would prefer to just do it in one line

Comment: _Sidenote:_ in one line: `tracks.each &Track.method(:create!)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.create!` class method actually [takes multiple args](https://github.com/mongomapper/mongomapper/blob/master/lib/mongo_mapper/plugins/querying.rb#L26). It uses arbitrary arity instead of taking one array argument.

You could do this, using the splat operator:

```
tracks = [{:name => "Obla di"}, {:name => "She Sang di"}]
Track.create!(*tracks)
```

NB: As you can see from the code, this is just sugar. MongoMapper still makes one insert per document.